# How to change wlan0 mac adress?

Tags: wireless

My native linux partition is connected with a yagi usb antenna and my virtual machine is a cloned setup of it, the problem is the mac adress that interfere but i could only change the mac adress of the native partition because of the specifics uses of the virtual machine ...

Answer (score 8):

Use macchanger.

This is the sample command:

```
macchanger --mac 00:11:22:33:44:55 wlan0
```

Answer (score 7):

This can be configured in Network Manager nowadays. Below is a screenshot in KDE (Kubuntu), but this should be very similar in regular Ubuntu (Unity).

[image]

Comment: just fyi put in the cloned address field on linux mint not the actual mac address field.  even though you can type in both fields.  works like a charm and so simple :)  used it to get my chromecast to work at a hotel that required a login screen, cloned my chromecast on the laptop then fired up the chromecast once the mac address was accepted.

Answer (score 0):

very simple click on your network icon in the task bar, click wlan0 , click on edit.. change the mac and save :)